# Multiple Un-killable Looping Processes Spawning

Tags: process, memory-usage, kill, duplicate

I'm desperately trying to work this one out, so thanks for taking a look.

Context:
Whilst trying to make a large file transfer from my Ubuntu PC to an external hard-drive, using rsync I believe, I think I may have tried to keep the transfer running after the PC logged-off / shutdown.

This is the only thing I can think off that may have led to my current problem.

Problem:

- PC froze initially. No mouse or keyboard input registered. Nothing.
- Restarted with power button and discovered via htop that almost all processes had duplicates waiting.
- Opening Opera browser would start 10 or so processes using 1T or more's worth of virtual memory.
- running htop it typically says 114 tasks, 374 thru, 1 running.
- running top it says 299 total tasks, 298 sleeping.
- Duplicates included root-user processes.
- Even when killed the duplicates would often recur.
- Some time spent killing these duplicates seemed to be helping, they seemed to disappear for good. Then I would kill a process that would end my user session and return me to the login page. When logged in again htop would show all the duplicates were back.
- even when running the machine from a live-boot USB, htop still shows duplicate processes / sleeping tasks at a system level.

Possible clues:

- noticed a faint high pitched buzz from the PC when this started. Would buzz on immediate startup with Lenovo logo, stop for a second when the screen went dark, before starting again when the Lenovo logo and Ubuntu logo appeared.
- similar effects to what I've read about a 'fork-bomb' in terms of looping processes that won't close. But no fork bomb code deliberately run. Highly probably I've messed something up myself.
- Running sudo htop, filtering by PID, the lowest number program that has a duplicate (presumably the earliest process duplicated) is a systemd-t command '/lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd', which has 1 duplicate (2 total).
- The next process to duplicate was root command 'usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon'which has 1 duplicate (2 total)
- single messagebu command (don't know if relevant) '/usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only'
- The next process to duplicate had many multiple processes and was the root command usr/sbin/osspd -f --dsp-slave=usr/lib/osspd/ossp-slave, which had 11 copies (12 total).

Solutions Attempted

- tried to use u-limit to limit number of processes on my user session to 10 processes. Seemed to keep memory use under 2gb for my normal user session, whereas the liveboot user showed memory use around 3.5gb for the same activity (just running htop in a terminal).
- Various killall processes. Seemed to work in a session but would resume upon next startup.
- Using sudo htop to kill processes individually. Same issue as above.
- Ran chkroot kit to search for any viruses which identified 7 suspicious folders/directories:

1. /usr/lib/debug/.build-id
2. /usr/lib/modules/5.15.0-46-generic/vdso/.build-id
3. /usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-125-lowlatency/vdso/.build-id
4. /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/uic/widget-plugins/.noinit
5. usr/lib/debug/.build-id
6. /usr/lib/modules/5.15.0-46-generic/vdso/.build-id
7. /usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-125-lowlatency/vdso/.build-id
   The last files listed seem to be the same as the first three.

Big Question:

- Even if I do a completely fresh install of Ubuntu on the PC, will this problem still persist?

I'm way out of my depth here, so if a fresh install will definitely remove the problem I'm tempted just to do that. But I can't tell if the problem is now at a deeper level on the machine.

Any help or insight will be VERY gratefully received.

Thank you so much.

**EDIT 16:30, 15/09/22**

Am including a screenshot of the current htop screen, ordered by PID.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kMHy.png)

**EDIT 16:31, 15/09/22**

Have run 'history' to check what happened with rsync and have posted the output of the last 100 lines or so. Am wondering whether it was not rsync but an earlier systemctl poweroff command?

History below:

- 150  htop
- 151  shutdown now
- 152  systemctlpoeroff -i
- 153  systemctl poweroff -i
- 154  htop
- 155  shutdown now
- 156  network
- 157  netcp
- 158  netcap
- 159  utils
- 160  netutils
- 161  htop
- 162  exit
- 163  htop
- 164  wpa_cli
- 165  shutdown now
- 166  htop
- 167  shutdown now
- 168  progress -w
- 169  htop
- 170  exit
- 171  rsync -r /home/ciaran/Documents/ /media/ciaran/Seagate Basic1/PC-Files-Backup-12-9-22/Documents
- 172  rsync -r /home/ciaran/Documents/ /media/ciaran/'Seagate Basic1'/PC-Files-Backup-12-9-22/Documents
- 173  progress -w
- 174  htop
- 175  shutdown now
- 176  top
- 177  clear
- 178  htop
- 179  ulimit -u 10
- 180  killall -STOP -u ciaran
- 181  killall -KILL -u ciaran
- 182  sudo killall -STOP -u ciaran
- 183  ulimit -u 100
- 184  killall -STOP
- 185  dropbox
- 186  dropbox start
- 187  clear
- 188  if [ $(pgrep -f java | wc -l) -gt 1 ]; then   echo "kill $(pgrep -f java | grep -v $(pgrep -of java) | sort -n | uniq | awk '{printf $1" "}')"; fi
- 189  progress -w
- 190  SIGSTOP
- 191  sudo killall -9 809
- 192  ps -o pid= -u ciaran | xargs kill
- 193  htop
- 194  sudo htop
- 195  service
- 196  man service
- 197  top
- 198  sudo htop
- 199  cd /lib/systemd
- 200  ls
- 201  vim systemd-timesyncd
- 202  service
- 203  man service
- 204  service --help
- 205  man service
- 206  sudo chkrootkit
- 207  sudo apt-get install chkrootkit
- 208  chkrootkit
- 209  sudo chkrootkit
- 210  man chkrootkit
- 211  chkrootkit
- 212  sudo chkrootkit
- 213  pstree
- 214  sudo htop
- 215  pstree
- 216  #!/bin/bash
- 217  if [ $(pgrep -f java | wc -l) -gt 1 ]; then kill $(pgrep -f java | grep -v $(pgrep-of java) | sort -n | uniq | awk '{printf$1" "}'); fi
- 218  sudo strace -r -o output.log -p 756
- 219  man whoopsie
- 220  whoopse
- 221  whoopsie
- 222  rsync /home/Ciaran/Documents/ /media/ciaran/'Seagate Basic1'/PC-Files-Backup-12-9-22/Documents
- 223  rsync -v home/ciaran/Documents/ /media/ciaran/'Seagate Basic1'/PC-Files-Backup-12-9-22/Documents
- 224  man rsync
- 225  strace ls
- 226  strace -i ls
- 227  rsync /home/ciaran/Documents/ /media/ciaran/'Seagate Basic1'/PC-Files-Backup-12-9-22/Documents2
- 228  cd ..
- 229  ls
- 230  sudo htop
- 231  sudo apt update
- 232  shutdown now
- 233  sudo htop
- 234  top
- 235  sudo top
- 236  history

**Screenshot of Htop showing Opera processes:**
[Htop Opera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoHTi.png)

Comment: If a fresh install doesn't fix the issue, it likely isn't fixable except by buying new hardware (and it means that something very, very, *very* strange has happened to corrupt your hardware such that it runs but constantly spawns new processes, I'm not sure if that's even possible). There isn't really anything the OS can do that can wreck your hardware in that way.

Comment: Some additional info on exactly what you did with rsync would help, as would disabling any cron jobs/systemd timers you added (and stopping rsync for good)

Comment: Hi Esther, thanks so much. I can't now actually remember what I did with rsync. Will it be stored in a log somewhere?

Comment: `history` command will show you your bash history. Depending how you have it configured and how much you've done since then, it might still contain the information.

Comment: Great, history does show it. Will posting it in the original question.

Comment: you also don't have to tag things with "edit" or the date: it's contained in the edit history. In general, when you edit your question, it should look as if you just posted it that way right now.

Comment: although most of this doesn't sound too concerning to me. Is something consuming CPU or memory? Is the 1 TB(?!) for Opera accurate, or was it 1 GB (makes sense)?

Comment: Thanks again Esther, you're being a great help. I've added another screenshot of htop now I'm running Opera with one tab open (this site). Still shows 1T under the VIRT collumn.

Comment: The PC still seems to be running so maybe I am worrying about nothing now, but I don't know if it's because the ulimit function is helping keep the number of processes down.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything wrong. Your `htop` looks perfectly normal, and "duplicate" userland processes are quite normal as well.

I believe you have discovered something you were not aware of before, but it's not a problem.

Here's an example from my own htop:

[image]

As you can see, in the left pane I've disabled userland processes, and in the right pane they are present *(they are indicated by a green color in `htop`, and you can see they have the same `PGRP` number)*.

I have disabled display of userland processes by default, since I believe they're mostly noise in the `htop` picture.

You can configure this in `htop` by:

- Go to <kbd>F2</kbd>`Setup`
- <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to select display options
- Navigate to `Hide userland process threads`
- Click <kbd>Space</kbd> to deactivate this option, and hide userland processes

If you do not experience seriously degraded performance as compared to before, I don't believe there is anything wrong (at least, duplicate processes are in itself not a symptom of anything wrong).

Comment: Hi Artur, thanks for the reassurance. I can see you htop screenshot now.

Comment: Thanks again Artur. Are there any go-to processes or procedures you go through when you're worried or unsure whether you've broken something? Hopefully I can avoid wasting people's time in future.

Comment: Are the multiple processes with red 1.1T in the VIRT section anything to worry about? The image is at the bottom of my original question.

Comment: I think that's standard browser behavior nowadays. Unfortunately, it's not so easy to give a simple answer if you're unsure whether something is broke. Asking here is fine - if it's off-topic or gets closed for some other reason, no harm done.

Comment: Thanks so much Artur. Take care!